# Doing Math with SQL entries

Tags: mysql, sql

so I am trying to use MySQL to look at the values of our database, and spit out the sum of the values in a column between 2 date ranges. Currently I have gotten it to at least select the correct range of dates using the code:

```
SELECT fuelDate, SUM(gallons)  
FROM fuel566243
WHERE fuelDate BETWEEN '2019-01-04' AND '2019-01-24'
GROUP BY fuelDate 
ORDER BY fuelDate
```

The issue with this code, is in the SUM column that gets generated, it just displays all the values of the gallons column, but doesn't add them up. Is there a way to do this in SQL and output a result? Or is it easier to just use a foreach loop to cycle through the array and add the values using PHP?

When I run the code above, it gives me this output. How do I then get the sum of the gallons column shown below? Is there a way to do that in SQL? Or would I need to use a loop to add the values using PHP?

```
| fuelDate | Gallons | | 
| 2019-01-04 | 53.8885 | |
| 2019-01-15 | 198.1700 | | 
| 2019-01-17 | 167.2750 | | 
| 2019-01-23 | 176.5620 | | 
| 2019-01-24 | 181.0240 | |
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Input, Actual Output, Expected Output? I thought Gordon's answer was correct for what you asked.

Comment: Yeah

I input 
`"SELECT fuelDate, SUM(gallons)  
FROM fuel566243
WHERE fuelDate BETWEEN '2019-01-04' AND '2019-01-24'
GROUP BY fuelDate 
ORDER BY fuelDate"`

and it outputs:

Fuel Date           gallons
2019-01-04        53.8885
2019-01-15        198.1700
2019-01-17        167.2750
2019-01-23        176.5620
2019-01-24        181.0240

Comment: Please `edit` (button under question text) your question and paste what you just commented there. It's unreadable in the comments section... Also Sample input would be the rows of data before the grouping, not the query

Comment: Got it, sorry haha. One day ill figure out what im doing on here haha

Comment: It gives the right result.  What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` defines the rows that are being returned.  You have included `gallons` as an aggregation key, so you have specified that you want a separate row for each value.

Simply remove the key from the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT fuelDate, SUM(gallons)  
FROM fuel566243
WHERE fuelDate BETWEEN '2019-01-04' AND '2019-01-24'
GROUP BY fuelDate 
ORDER BY fuelDate;
```

If you want the total during the period, then you want an aggregation with *no* `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(gallons)  
FROM fuel566243
WHERE fuelDate BETWEEN '2019-01-04' AND '2019-01-24';
```

Comment: I tried this method, it got rid of the gallons column, so now it only shows 2 columns (which is good), but it still doesn't create a sum of the gallons column. It just shows the values of those cells. 

I am wanting it to output a value for the total value of the gallons column.

Comment: Then don't goup at all, and remove `fuelDate` from SELECT.

Comment: Thank you Paul <3